# How to handle runtime exceptions in dot net 6 web api project?

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-web-api, runtimeexception

In my asp net core 6 web api project I am handling several exceptions like NotFound 404, Unprocessable entity 422, Unauthorised 403, and all unhandled exceptions as 500 internal error. I am not sure this is the proper way to handle these. But currently some runtime exceptions arise in the project mainly type conflicts which arise only at the runtime and causes crash of application. I am new to dot net 6 and also exception handling, please guide me so that the application does not crash in production.

Comment: Specific questions require specific analysis, and the answers I give are commonly used in work.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to know what error 400 and error 500 in the Http Status Code stand for.

**In a nutshell:**

**400 ：**  The Web Application is up and running, and the error is related to the application configuration.

**500 ：**  The Web Application is not running, has failed to start, or has an internal error in one of the methods.

---

Take, for example, a bus that starts up and can run on the street. 401 errors are similar to card swipe device failure, unable to identify passengers, 404 failures are similar to the glass washer running out, etc. related minor errors, but they do not affect the operation of the vehicle.

A 500 error is like the engine won't catch fire at all, won't run, or hit a special road section (special method) and will stall.

---

**How to solve it?**

The premise is that you need to ensure that the program runs properly in the local Visual Studio.

*400 Error：*

1. you can enable failed request tracing and find which request will face 400 error. You can set range like 400-499.
2. you can check event viewer logs.
3. [you can enable stdout log.](http://docs.lacunasoftware.com/en-us/articles/amplia/on-premises/windows/enable-stdout-log.html)

*500 Error：*

1. Use debugdiag collect to capture the dump and analyze the stacks.
2. enable ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development, and you can find the error details.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [Jason Pan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73301293/13092211);

Generally, errors with a `500` error code will prevent the application from starting or cause the application to crash. For the details of the error, you need to log this error.

In the new .net 6 startup template, add `try-catch` block;

```
try
{
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

    // Add services to the container.
    
    // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    
    app.Run();

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //logging
}
```

> You can use `try-catch` in Program.cs in older initial configuration versions.

You can use middleware to prevent crashes from other errors;

```
public class ExceptionMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public ExceptionMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {  try
        {
            //Continue processing
            if (_next != null)
                await _next.Invoke(context);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {          
            //Log the exception if you want

            if (!context.Response.HasStarted)
            {
                var response = "An error occured, please try again!";

                var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(response);

                context.Response.ContentType = "application/json"; ;
                context.Response.StatusCode = 200;

                await context.Response.WriteAsync(json);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
public static class ErrorMiddlewareExtension
{
    public static IApplicationBuilder UseCustomExceptionHandler(this IApplicationBuilder builder) => builder.UseMiddleware<ExceptionMiddleware>();
}
```

And use this middleware in your startup configuration;

```
try
{
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

    // Add services to the container.

    builder.Services.AddControllers();
    builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
    builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

    var app = builder.Build();

    // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI();
    }

    app.UseCustomExceptionHandler();

    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.MapControllers();

    app.Run();

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //logging
}
```

With this middleware, you don't need to write `try-catch` anywhere in the application except in special cases.

> The middleware order is important, so try to use this middleware at the top so you can cover the entire request pipeline.